# What is different between (NN, Tensorflow/keras)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

What is difference between this

1. `Tensor("IteratorGetNext:0", shape=(None, None), dtype=int64)`

and this

2. `Tensor("IteratorGetNext:0", shape=(None, 100, 10), dtype=int64)`

I found two tensorflow/keras codes, print input data and got this
they both formatic text

I want to train NN, but I can't understand difference between this two variants (I think understanding difference btwn this two is important for further learning NN)

Comment: They just have different shapes, I am not sure what other difference you are looking about.

Answer (score 0):

> Tensor("IteratorGetNext:0", shape=(None, None), dtype=int64)

This line of code indicates the tensor has an unspecified numbers of rows and columns.
The None dimension means that the shape of tensor can vary along this axis.

> Tensor("IteratorGetNext:0", shape=(None, 100, 10), dtype=int64)

This line of code indicates the tensor has an unspecified number of data points, which has a fixed shape of 100 rows and 10 columns.

The first dimension is None, it indicates the number of samples can vary, but each samples has a fixed shape of 100x10.